# Pass array of data from form, to ajax, to PHP post file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I'll try and keep this short. 
I have a form who's input fields (54 of them) are auto filled with data from a database. The ID of each input field is assigned with an ID using a PHP `while` loop. The user can edit the values and click submit. When the form is submitted, the data is passed to an array in jquery. I want to be able to pass that array from ajax to PHP via POST.

Form/submit page

```
$settings = array();
$counter = 0;

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $settings[$counter] = $row['value'];

        echo "<tr>
                <td>" . $row[$settings] . "</td>
                <td><input type=\"text\" id=\"" . $counter . "\" value=\"" 
                                 . $settings[$counter] . "\"></td>";
        counter++;
    }
}

mysqli_close($svr_link);
```

jQuery script (inside of the form/submit page)

```
    $('#update').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var settings = [];
    for (i=0; i<55; i++) {
        settings[i] = $('#' + i).val();
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "pages/post.php",
        data: {settings:settings},
        success: function(data) {
            $('#message').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

My question is:

1. Did I properly set up that data array in the ajax call?
2. How do I pull and deal with the data array in the post.php file?

Let me know if I omitted something relevant

Comment: The data in PHP will be in the `$_POST` array if passed correctly.

Comment: So I correctly made the $_POST array in the ajax call? How do I parse it in the PHP post file?

Comment: You'll have to `print_r($_POST)` in your to see what you have. You may want to think about converting the array to JSON before you send it, then decode the JSON on the PHP side for parsing.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there an advantage to encoding it in JSON as opposed to passing it as an array as I did?

Comment: I find JSON to be "cleaner" to handle.

Comment: Okay, so how would I encode the array in JSON in the jquery script, pass it through ajax and then decode/parse in PHP?

Comment: `json_encode($settings)` in your first PHP script, then you don't have to loop in your JavaScript, just make `settings` equal to `JSON.stringify(<?php echo the encoded json;?>)` and then `json_decode($_POST['settings'], true)` to get an array you can work with in your second PHP script.

Comment: Got it, thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

If you're sending array data as JSON, it'd be recomendable to set `dataType` in your ajax set up at client.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "pages/post.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {settings:settings},
    success: function(data) {
        $('#message').html(data);
    }
});
```

At server side, use `json_decode` function to get an array, that way you can easily work with data. It'd be something like this:

```
json_decode($_POST['settings'], true);
```

Comment: That was a typo, my mistake. I rewrote the code while looking at my other computer. It shows as `i` in my code.

Comment: Be careful, `dataType` setting is _the type of data that you are expecting back from the server_, as per [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).
I've never tested it, but i suppose that if you want to send a JSON in the request content, you have to set `contentType: 'json'` and then pass the JSON string in the `data` setting

Answer (score 2):

Add `name` attribute to all the inputs in array form

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $settings[$counter] = $row['value'];

        echo "<tr>
                <td>{$row[$settings]}</td>
                <td>
                    <input 
                        type=\"text\" 
                        id=\"{$counter}\" 
                        name=\"settings[{$counter}]\" 
                        value=\"{$settings[$counter]}\"
                        >
                </td>";
        counter++;
    }
```

Then add an `id` to the form (if you don't have a form tag, place the id on some HTML element that contains all the inputs, like probably the `table`), ad rely on jQuery `serializeArray()`

```
let data = $('#formId').find(':input').serializeArray();
```

So, your code become:

```
$('#update').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    let data = $('#formId').find(':input').serializeArray();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "pages/post.php",
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#message').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

jQuery.serializeArray()

> Encode a set of form elements as an array of names and values.

[from jQuery.serializeArray() documentation](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)